# What does it mean when there are variables equal to a function?

Tags: python, pandas, function, variables

I'm trying to understand what this script, which is the body of a function, means:

```
while True:
    city, month, day = get_filters()
    df = load_data(city, month, day)
```

The city, month and day variables are objects returned from get_filters() and the df variable is assigned to loading data into a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that get_filters() returns 3 objects - city, month, and day are all set to the output of that function, respectively.

df is then set to the output of whatever the load_data function does, which according to you is returning a pandas dataframe

For example, if you have something like this:

```py
def example():
    return 1, 2, 3

one, two, three = example()

print(one, two, three)
```

your output would be

1 2 3

Comment: Great, that's helped with my understanding of it, thanks!